# Spark Foreach Standard Deviation Works For First Only

Tags: java, apache-spark, math, standard-deviation

Good afternoon, I am currently using Java and Apache's Spark with a CSV file of 60,000+ rows and 400+ columns of the following structure:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| a | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| b | 1 | 4 | 6 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Essentially, I would like to calculate the sample and popular standard deviations of each row. I am using the following code and for some reason only the first row has the correct SD's.

```
joined.javaRDD().foreach(r -> {
    double[] _expressions = new double[407];
    for(int i = 0; i < 407; i++) {
        _expressions[i] = Double.parseDouble(r.get(i + 1).toString());
    }
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _expressions.length; i++) {
        sum += _expressions[i];
    }
    double avg = sum / _expressions.length;
    double sum2 = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _expressions.length; i++) {
        sum2 += (_expressions[i] - avg) * (_expressions[i] - avg);
    }
    double var = sum2 / (_expressions.length - 1);
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(var));
});
```

I am using Excel with a sample of 10 rows to compare and I can see only the first row is correct. I don't think thread safety is an issue, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your lambda looks ok to me, supposing that its argument is always a `List` of exactly 407 `String`s that have the proper format to be parsed as `double`s.  If you are not getting the results you expect then my first guess would be that there is an issue with the input.  I cannot do any more than guess, however, until and unless you present a [mcve].

Comment: If the goal is just to compute the per-row sd's, and it's not essential to use Spark, maybe you can use R for this task. 60,000 times 400 times 16 = 384 times 10^6; I'm guessing it's not too big for R. I suspect `parseDouble` is going to a serious bottleneck, and maybe `read.csv` would be substantially faster. Just a guess.

Comment: Your lambda seems ok _at first sight_, but there is not enough information to investigate and answer. Could we check for instance how you produce the RDD `joined`? Also, have you tried with a minimal reproducible example - e.g. 2-3 lines and 2-3 columns?